# replace body:background with javascript

Tags: replace, background

Simple HTML,CSS,JS website. I'd like to start off with a black background, and after a few seconds switch to an image background. The problem I'm having is that my image background is sitting behind the black background, so it is not visible.

**HTML**

```
<body id="body" onload="changeBG()">
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 100%;
    min-height:100%; /* this fixes bgimage issue on android */
    background: black;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**JS**

```
var body = document.getElementById('body');
function changeBG() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.body.style.background = "url('images/background-stars.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed";
        }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove html from CSS Rule that is

FROM

```
html, body {
```

TO

```
body {
```

And also FYI, you are applying background image at every 3000ms of time interval. It should get applied only once I guess.